# Storyboard Modal Segue with delegate

Tags: ios, xcode, delegates, storyboard, segue

I've made an app using iOS6 unwind segues not realising they weren't in iOS5 and so i'm taking it apart in order to support iOS5.  So far i've worked out that I need to use delegates in order to get information back to my root view from the modal segue view and have a couple of good examples to follow and i'm quietly confident I get it.

Currently the modal segue is generated via the storyboard however, not via code.

In order to set it's delegate as my root view will I need to generate it via code instead or is there a way via the storyboards?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Before performing the segue the program will call the method `- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender` in the sourceViewController (the view controller that calls the segue). In this method you can give the destinationViewController a reference to self:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [segue.destinationViewController setDelegate:self];
}
```

Of course you need the property in the destinationViewController:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<yourProtocol> delegate;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I thought and tried this initially with no joy, tried again and worked, must have had a typo in the segue indentifier.  Thanks! :)

Comment: Glad to help. Any question, please ask.

Comment: could be wrong but shouldn't that be `id<yourProtocol> delegate;`?